# Is there possibility to sum timings from SQL in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am at end of creating one application for working time monitoring, so now i stuck with one calculation.

So i have database table with few columns

> (ID, USER_ID, MONTH, START_TIME, END_TIME)

, so here my client enter data using date("Y-m-d H:i:s").

Now my client want to make calculation how much is the total time

> "(END_TIME - START TIME)" per USER_ID and MONTH.

And that to be displayed in table as USER, MONTH, TOTAL TIME.

How is that possible to be solved by using MySQL and PHP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `START_TIME` and `END_TIME` are datetime data type, you may use query:

```
SELECT user_id, month, (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(end_time)-UNIX_TIMESTAMP(start_time)) AS total_time FROM ... WHERE 1 GROUP BY user_id AND month
```

and check https://phpdelusions.net/pdo_examples/select for use sql in PHP.